# Delete first 'n' rows from csv file and keep header

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Well, I need to check if number of rows >= 'x' and if true, delete first 'n' rows

Currently I load csv to df, drop lines and load it back, but it's not very clean and efficient way to do this. Do you know any other?

Here is algorithm in human language as I can see it:

```
~~~~~~~~~~
if number_of_rows(file.csv) >= 3000:
   del(file.csv[1:1499]) # as first line is header, we wouldn't want to delete it*
~~~~~~~~~~
```

UPD: forgot to add, that file is growing every minute, and i need only like last 1.5k rows of it.
The code is a part of a loop btw

Comment: Please, add algorithm in a language a computer can understand, i.e. share your code, or at least a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a context manager if you are certain the file will fit into memory.

```
n = 25 # your line count.
with open('/path/to/your_file.csv') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    lines = len(data)
    if lines >= n:

        df = pd.read_csv(data,skiprows=range((1, lines-1500)) #using range will keep your header.
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that file is growing every minute, and i need to read only last 1.5k rows and with 'skiprows' it will eventually overgrow

Comment: thanks, it did. I just needed to change the line `df = pd.read_csv(data,skiprows=range(lines-1500, lines-1))` to `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',skiprows=range(1, lines-1500))`